# Electronjs ipcMain doesn't send message to ipcRenderer

Tags: electron

I'm trying to send message/data from ipcMain to ipcRender asynchronously, followed the codes described there - https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main, In main -

```
// In main process.
  const {ipcMain} = require('electron')
  ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', (event, arg) => {
    console.log(arg) // prints "ping"
    event.sender.send('asynchronous-reply', 'pong')
  })
```

In renderer -

```
// In renderer process (web page).
  const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')
  ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-reply', (event, arg) => {
    console.log(arg) // prints "pong"
  })
  ipcRenderer.send('asynchronous-message', 'ping')
```

It sends message from renderer to main successfully, but main suppose to send back message to renderer but it doesn't.

I've tried webContents send message too but no success -

```
win.webContents.send('asynchronous-reply', 'pong1')
```

I'm using using node 8.9.3, Chrome 61.0.3163.100, Electron 2.0.5 and macOS 10.13.3. Here are the details - https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/13743

Appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Just to make sure: Do you check printing of "pong" in devtools console right?

Comment: Yes, I turned the devtools using  win.webContents.openDevTools()

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @ancode. Figured it out, The messages sent from **Renderer** to **Main** was printing in **Terminal Console** and message sent from **Main** to **Renderer** was printing in **Web Dev Console**(As a new electron developer, I completely missed it, was expecting all messages in Terminal Console)